# Why i am using Random.range(0,2) and only generate me the number 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`private int _randomInt =  Random.Range(0,2);`

I am using C# with Unity3d
And this Debug always return me 0 and never never 1 or 0. Only 0 Why?

`Debug.Log("The random number is: " + _randomInt );`

Comment: You call `Random.Range(0,2)` **once** and store the result in `_randomInt`. You then read the value of `_randomInt` many times... But the value doesn't change. If you want to generate more random numbers, call `Random.Range(0,2)` multiple times.

Comment: That should populate `_randomInt` with 0, 1, or 2. You aren't mistakenly expecting `Deug.Log("The random number is: " + _randomInt );` to output a different number each time you call that, are you? I ask because other people have made that mistake in the past. As canton7 says, you're only assigning a value to `_randomInt` once and then not changing it.

Comment: I am using the class ```using UnityEngine;```

Comment: @MiguelÁngel `UnityEngine` is irrelevant - it's because you're using a _field_ and not a _computed property_.

Comment: When you pass in a integer as the range, the max value is excluded. So the output can only be 0 or 1. The probability of getting a 0 is 50 percent. Try changing the random seed and see if you get a different result.

Comment: @MiguelÁngel: How are you testing this?  How often is the class which contains this field re-initialized?  If you re-start the whole application multiple times, what are the results of the random number generation across many tests?

Comment: it worked for me the way Dai said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `private int _randomInt` is a *field*, which means it stores a value, and the initial value of that field is the result of evaluating `Random.Range(0,2)` *once* (which happens when you call `new YourClassName()` in your code - or Unity might be calling it for you).
- If you want `_randomInt` to return a new random value every time it's used then you need to change it to a computed property - or a normal method call.

  - Note that using an underscore-prefixed camelCase name is a naming convention that is only ever used for fields (and many people, including myself, use underscores to denote `static` fields, while using `this.` for instance fields). For properties `PascalCase` should always be used (and not `camelCase` nor `_underscorePrefixedCamelCase` nor `snake_case`).
- Change your code to this:

  ```
  private int RandomValue => Random.Range(0,2);

  //

  Debug.Log("The random number is: " + RandomValue );
  ```
- The above code uses the (relatively recently introduced) *expression-bodied property* syntax using a `=>`, in earlier versions of C#, or if the property's logic requires more than 1 line of code then use the long-form:

  ```
  private int RandomValue
  {
       get
       {
           return Random.Range(0,2);
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me a lot! But it was not clear to me the syntax of ```=>```.  Could you explain it to me in another way? I never saw such a syntax when creating variables

Comment: @MiguelÁngel It is incorrect to refer to a member property as a "variable": the term "variable" only describes non-`const` locals, fields, parameters and globals (and C# doesn't have globals). As for the `=>` syntax, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members - and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: So you should call properties , to everything that has characteristics of x object , right? I do not know if I explained well.
By the way I also want to apply good programming practices so I should investigate where camelCase and PascalCase are used
Thank you very much for your help, time and dedication.